# What does "Step up the two of us" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

Can anyone explain to me, what does "step up" mean in the song *Imagine* by Ariana Grande, which she says at the beginning:

> "Step up the two of us, nobody knows us
>   get in the car like skrrt"

Comment: Two or tow?????

Comment: it is "two", sorry haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Step up**](http://www.finedictionary.com/step-up.html)

Comes from an [American Baseball metaphor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/step_up_to_the_plate#English) - to "step up to the plate", by doing so you indicate to the bowler that you are ready to take the ball that he throws at you. It means "Take your turn".

"Step up the two of us" would therefore seem to mean let's take our turn together (On a night out).

> Idioms Step up a gear - If you step up a gear, you perform noticeably
>   better, especially in sport.
>   *** Step up to the plate - If someone steps up to the plate, they take on or accept a challenge or a responsibility.

In the context of the song lyric it seems to mean "rise to the occasion" as [here](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/phrases/step-up-to-the-plate/#.XBwKwbjwtXg).

[rise to the occasion](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rise+to+the+occasion)

> To find the ability to deal with an unexpected challenge.

Comment: Din't get that, so "step up the two of us means what

Comment: @Augusto Gracia I'll edit my answer to explain.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now, another friend of mine said that it means something like, stepping up to the curb to get ready to get into their uber/car.

Comment: There's no bowler in American baseball.  Do you mean the pitcher?

Comment: @Augusto Gracia thanks for the accepted answer thing. Just to say, the expression has been around at least 100 years before uber was invented. :D Kristina Lopez, apologies, pitcher, yes. I'm from the home of cricket so that habit of thought prevails.